# loop gets stuck when using SET with /P

Tags: loops, batch-file, variables, parameters

As some might know I'm working on a script to collect informations of a computer to make the process very fast. No I'm kind of stuck because I wanted to write the decoded result into a textfile without spamming it with new lines. The problem is as soon as I want to do add the `/p` parameter it stops after the first decoding round.

```
@echo offsure
set list=89 86 51 84 49 55 52 49 52 49
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR %%X IN (%list%) DO (
    set /p temp=%%~nX
    cmd /c exit !temp:~0,7!
    set temp2=!=exitcodeAscii! 
    echo !temp2!
) >> C:\TestConverters.txt
Echo. >> C:\TestConverters.txt
pause
```

here is the sourcecode I'm currently using. If I remove the /p parameter it works perfectly fine. So now I'm actually just trying to improve the test result I use in the script to have at least this little bit worked out already.

Comment: It's a little bloated, `%%X`=`%%~nX`=`!temp!`=`!temp:~0,7!`

Comment: @DodgyCodeException: it's an undocumented internal variable, which translates errorlevel to ASCII (listed at [SS64](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`set /p temp=%%~nX` will ask the user for a variable named `temp`, presenting a prompt of `%%~nX`. Probably not what you want.

I guess you want to write `!temp2!` without a line break.
Yes there is a `set /p` trick to do so, but a) you used it at the wrong place and b) you don't want the user to enter something (which will pause your script), but take input from `NUL` instead:

Replace

```
echo !temp2!
```

with

```
<nul set /p =!temp2!
```

(and remove the trailing space at the line before)

Following Compo's comment, your code can be simplified like:

```
@echo off 
set list=89 86 51 84 49 55 52 49 52 49
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
(
  FOR %%X IN (%list%) DO (
    cmd /c exit %%X
    <nul set /p =!=exitcodeAscii!
  ) 
  echo.
)>>C:\TestConverters.txt
pause
```

Comment: Dude thanks a lot. Now I will only need to filter out the informations as they are in the var "list" and then I am finally done with the setup for the final script. Really pal thanks a lot. Let me know if I could do anything for you. Also nice explanation. :-)

Answer (score 1):

A quick example, *if you don't really have a need to use `SET/P`*:

```bat
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "list=89 86 51 84 49 55 52 49 52 49"
SET "variable="
FOR %%X IN (%list%) DO (CMD/C EXIT %%X
    Set "variable=!variable!!=EXITCODEASCII!")
IF DEFINED variable >"C:\TestConverters.txt" ECHO(%variable%
PAUSE
```

Comment: probably faster to first build the line then write it in one go than writing each character with the  `set /p` method.

Comment: it's not a question of speed but of function. If it works perfectly fine for me then I'am happy for it. So I won't have any need to make it faster. It would probably be only faster by 1-10 ms which is not really that much. It's not as if I hade to do that for like 10 million lines or values.

Comment: @M.Stephen, speed isn't an issue, efficiency however should be, _where practicable_. Stephans point should have read that my suggestion was probably more efficient. I commented on your question first, Stephan based his response around my comment yet implied that my later answer was probably faster. You decided to ignore all of that and accept his answer instead, _which is of course your perogative_. I see no benefit in you arguing his point four days later, _beneath my perfectly good answer_, whilst continuing ignore the contribution I made!

Answer (score 0):

Or you can try this.

```
 @echo off
 set list=89 86 51 84 49 55 52 49 52 49
 SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
 FOR %%X IN (%list%) DO (
 set temp=%%~nX
 cmd /c exit !temp:~0,7!
 set temp2=!=exitcodeAscii!
 <nul set /p =!temp2!
 ) >> C:\BACKUPS\TestConverters.txt
 Echo. >> C:\BACKUPS\TestConverters.txt
 pause
```